# Appending a DOM element at a specific point in between HTML string within a parent

Tags: javascript, html

I am searching through a paragraph/div element for the specific character of ^ with wishes to replace the following contents inside a newly created SPAN element and rise it (making indices). All is successful except for the location at where I append my SPAN element. I wish to append it to the location that I find said character, however, I don't have any lead to find that location except the index that the character is found.

I know that it is possible to insertAfter() but that won't work in this situation as I am attempting to append the element after a certain character within a paragraph/div rather than after a certain element.

```html
            <div class="codeBlock">
                <span style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 20px;">Product Rule</span><br><br><br>
                    f(x) = u * v<br>
                        f'(x) = u'v + v'u<br>
                        <br>
                <br>
                <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px">I.E.</span> // Check<br><br>
                    f(x) = x^3 + 9
            </div>
```

```
function quill() {

        var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName("codeBlock");
        for (block of blocks) {

            for (let i = 0; i < block.textContent.length; i++) {
                var ch = block.textContent[i];

                if (ch == "^") {
                    // Loop until space
                    var l = i+1;
                    var superscript = document.createElement("SPAN");
                    var indice = "";
                    do {
                        indice += block.textContent[l];

                        l++;
                    } while (block.textContent[l] != " ");

                    superscript.textContent = indice;
                    superscript.className = "superscript";
                    block.appendChild(superscript);

                    console.log(indice);
                }

            }

        }


    }
    quill();
```

When I append the element, html would look like, for example:

```html
<p>
f(x) = x^2 /*Found the character*/ + 6
<span>2</span> /*So it appends the element at the end*/
</p>
```

when I am trying to get something like this:

```html
<p>
f(x) = x^2 /*Oh! Found the character and position, 
append element here in between x^2 and + 6*/<span>2</span> + 6
</p>
```

Comment: *"I am searching through a paragraph/div element for the specific character of ^ with wishes to replace the following contents inside a newly created SPAN element and rise it (making indices)."* What? In your post there's not one ^ anywhere.  Also what do you mean *"...and rise it (making indices)"*?

Comment: ooft whoops, there was one until I realised I solved the question incorrectly, so I redid it without realising that the part I redid was the one with indices. I've changed the example but the same "error" still occurs. Rising it as in, rather than reading x^2 it would be x and a small "2" in the top right like a superscript.

Comment: You mean `x<sup>2</sup>`?

Comment: Yeah, I just learnt that that exists after SimonRabbit's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should use regex for that

```html
function quill() {

        var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName("codeBlock");
        for (block of blocks) {

          block.innerHTML = block.innerHTML.replace(/(\^\d+)/, function(item){return '<sup>'+item+'</sup>';});
                }
            }
    quill();
```